# Detecting mime-type of a MySQL BLOB in Java

Tags: java, mysql, blob, mime-types, detection

Yes I know that we **shouldn't store images on a database**, thanks.

That said, is there a way to detect in java the mime type of a BLOB stored in mysql?

It is only for images (.gif, .png, .jpeg, etc.) I don't need a common purpose tool.

Thanks a lot guys

> Bonus points if the proposed
>   solution does not involve 3rd party
>   libs :)

Comment: There is no reason why you shouldn't store your images in a database, and there is no reason why you shouldn't use a 3rd party lib. There are at least two good ones, but I can't recall their names at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that you can take a look at the headers. You need to read the data into a byte array and then examine the bytes to see if they match up to the headers for the different file-types.

For example, for a GIF, the first three bytes are "GIF" (47<sub>16</sub> 49<sub>16</sub> 46<sub>16</sub>) followed by either "87a" (38<sub>16</sub> 37<sub>16</sub> 61<sub>16</sub>) or "89a" (38<sub>16</sub> 39<sub>16</sub> 61<sub>16</sub>).

So something like this should work (uses a `FileInputStream` for demonstration purposes, but you can get the binary data from a BLOB by using [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28int%29) or [`ResultSet#getBinaryStream(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28java.lang.String%29)):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IdentifyImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("sample.gif");

            //The following are in base 10
            byte[] gifHeader87a = {71, 73, 70, 56, 55, 97};
            byte[] gifHeader89a = {71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97};

            byte[] bytes = new byte[6];
            in.read(bytes, 0, 6);

            if(Arrays.equals(gifHeader89a, bytes) || Arrays.equals(gifHeader87a, bytes)) {
               System.out.println("It's a GIF!");
            }

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to look up the bytes in the header for other file types (like JPG, PNG, etc.). Not sure if this is the best way. Someone may have a better solution.

As far as 3rd-party libraries, [jMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) is pretty good. This is probably the easiest solution :).

**EDIT**

I found [this article](http://www.mikekunz.com/image_file_header.html) here that lists header information for different file types. There is some sample code, but it's written in another language (Clarion).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, storing images in databases is a-ok if you remember that you can always employ caching strategies to avoid certain issues. And modern computers tend to be able to handle the load for most scenarios. Anyhow, a key thing to remember when storing the blob is to store the mimetype with it on the way in as it tends to be pretty easy to divine then.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this is sound advice but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It could have -- unclear if you are still in the design stages where you can fix this or if you've got alot of data you need to map mime-types for. Even in that case, I would rather run something offline to map the not changing mimetype and modify the app to grab it up-front than to map it on the fly, looking it up could get a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea to store binary in databases because if this grow up, it can be very slow.

Even though you want to do this, I think it is better to store the mime type when you are storing the binary.